# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/instyle/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mailchimp.bak/mailchimp.php on line 1189

Tags: wordpress, mailchimp

When submitting the form, this error appears at the top of the page.

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/mailchimp.bak/mailchimp.php on line 1189`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your mailchimp plugin, and this will go away.